# List of idiomatic word pairs

Tags: terminology, idioms

I remember seeing somewhere a dictionary of idiomatic word pairs for use in programming.

Like `get`-`set`, `open`-`close`, `allocate`-`free` and so on.

Does anyone remember an URL?

Comment: setup-teardown, create-destroy, begin-end. It bugs me that init(ialise) doesn't seem to pair very well...

Comment: java-slow? perl-noise? c++-abomination? :-P

Comment: insert-delete, add-remove, enable-disable, grant-revoke, read-write, view-modify, load-save.

Comment: BTW, what pairs with store? Fetch?

Comment: Hmm, I would say so.  But sometimes "load" also pairs with "store", e.g. when talking about memory loads and stores on a CPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two short lists of such pairs in Code Complete, one for function names, one for variable names.  You can search for "Use Opposites Precisely" using amazon's look inside feature if you don't have the book.

Comment: Cool, you gave me new keywords to search! Thanks! The list I've seen  was longer, but this is a start.

Comment: I've accepted the "closest to what I want" question. Still looking for the url though...

Answer (score 3):

Building on ergosys' answer:

From Code Complete 2, Chapter 11, p. 264:

Common Opposites in Variable Names

- Begin/end
- first/last
- locked/unlocked
- min/max
- next/previous
- old/new
- opened/closed
- visible/invisible
- source/target
- source/destination
- up/down

Answer (score 2):

Never seen a list generally aimed at programming, however PowerShell has such a list: [Cmdlet verbs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714428%28VS.85%29.aspx). Pairings are highlighted for each verb where they exist.

And while much of PowerShell's strive for consistency on the command line comes from standardizing those verbs some of the pairings may be appropriate in other contexts as well.

Comment: Thanks, but, that is not the list I search for.

Comment: cmdlet verb link broken - maybe this helps? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands

Comment: or this -- they are not paired but joining them should be close to obvious: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands

Answer (score 1):

English is not my first language but aren't those [antonyms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposite_%28semantics%29#Antonyms_.28gradable_opposites.29) rather than idiomatic pairs?

In Linux you can use wordnet to search for antonyms

> sudo apt-get install wordnet

```
wn open -antsv
```

`-ants` for antonyms and `v` for verbs. You can also search for `(n | a | r) – antonym for noun | adjective | adverbs`.

Comment: Most of these words are, indeed, antonyms. But not all antonyms are idiomatic pairs in the sense of my question. See store-fetch vs. store-load in the comment above. Different use cases, different pairs. Which words are paired and when -- that is where idioms are. (P.S. English is not my mother's tongue either.)

Comment: A comfortable way to search for antonym pairs in general is a good thing, thanks. However, I'd like to find a list which specifies *established practice* of using such words in code.